# how can i directly load Document to devexpress spreadsheet not save in local

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm trying to make a program using devexpress that uploads and loads directly without going through a local.
I implemented the upload function, but there is no part to load it.
Use loadDocument provided, but its parameter is fileStream.
It seems that I need to use FtpWebRequest after converting to fileStream. What should I do?

```
''''
string user = "";
string pwd = "";
FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://blahblah/testExcel2.xlsx");
req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pwd);
req.UseBinary = false;
req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
using (FileStream aa = (FileStream)req.GetRequestStream())
{
    spreadsheetControl.LoadDocument(aa, DocumentFormat.Xlsx);
}
''''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accordingly to this [this](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraSpreadsheet.SpreadsheetControl.LoadDocument(System.IO.Stream-DevExpress.Spreadsheet.DocumentFormat)), SpreadsheetControl LoadDocument method receive any Stream, not only FileStream, so just pass response stream to it:

```
FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://blahblah/testExcel2.xlsx");
....
var response = req.GetResponse();
using (var responseStream = response.GetStream()) {
    spreadsheetControl.LoadDocument(responseStream, DocumentFormat.Xlsx);
}
```